# not working pass variable in render_template

Tags: python, flask

i am using python with flask. i want to send variable to html. getting html output.
ı pass filename variable with render_template. but i dont show in output variable in html
this my python code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    #cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
        #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO upload (title) VALUES (%s)", (filename,))
        #conn.commit()
        #os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        filenamea = 'result_'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.png'
        input_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        output_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filenamea)
        #session = new_session() 
        input = Image.open(input_path)
        output = remove(input)
        output.save(output_path)
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
  
@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    #print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)
```

this my html code:

```
<body>
    {% if filename %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{url_for('display_image', filename=filename)}}">
        </div>
    {% endif %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Image Backgroud Cleaner</header>
    <form action="#">
      <input class="file-input" type="file" name="file" multiple hidden>
      <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
      <p>Browse File to Upload</p>
    </form>
    <section class="progress-area"></section>
    <section class="uploaded-area"></section>
  </div>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='script2.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1hI7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The excerpts above are evidently an incomplete piece of a whole application.  Ideally, queries should be reduced to a minimal reproducible example that can be simulated without depending on the rest of your application.  This isn't said to be critical but rather to engender your patience and grace if contributors like me have had to make assumptions about your specific scenario to answer your question.

The most pivotal assumption I've made is that the included html text is the template named `index.html`.  Incidentally, it is importing `script2.js`.  Only you know what that script is doing (not to belabor the point) so please pardon if you've already addressed the following suggestions in that javascript file or elsewhere.

Neither of the routes posted above have a GET method that will return `index.html`.  `<form action="#">` suggests that you are using the upload_image route for both the GET and POST of `index.html`, so the absence of a corresponding route supporting the GET method is very likely one of the problems that you're facing.

There are at least two approaches you could try to add a corresponding route supporting the GET method that returns `index.html`:

**Method A - Update upload_image route to support GET method**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # All the POST logic goes here
    else:
        # All the GET logic goes here
        return render_template('index.html')
```

**Method B - Create a corresponding new route**

```
@app.route('/upload_page', methods=['GET'])
def upload_page():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

A reason for preferring method B is that you can leverage the upload_image route elsewhere to upload files in your application in different templating contexts if you haven't constrained it to `index.html`.  I've favored method B in my `index.html` example below.  Note that I've changed `<form action="#"` to `<form action="/"` so that it routes explicitly to the base route on POST.

Not only do you need to add a route that supports the GET method and returns `index.html`, but you also need to add `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` as attributes of the form in `index.html`.  Otherwise it will always default as a GET request and the intended POST will fail.

The `hidden` attribute is preventing the file input from rendering.  If you're not intentionally using it for an unstated purpose, remove it.

You also need a submit input or other interface of some sort in `index.html` to submit the upload form.

Depending on if and how you configured an upload folder path, you may be running into issues with the route `@app.route('/display/<filename>')`.  You actually don't need this route at all if you leverage the default by adding a folder named `static` in your application root directory.  You need only change the `url_for` argument from `display_image` to `static` for this to work.

Given the above adjustments, `index.html` now looks like this:

```
<body>
    {% if filename %}
        <div>
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=filename)}}">
        </div>
    {% endif %}
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Image Backgroud Cleaner</header>
    <form action="/" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input class="file-input" type="file" name="file" multiple>
      <input type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
      <p>Browse File to Upload</p>
    </form>
    <section class="progress-area"></section>
    <section class="uploaded-area"></section>
  </div>
  <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='script2.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

With these adjustments, you now should be getting the output variable `filename` that your question stated you were not getting in `index.html` and the `<img>` preview of `filename` should be visible in the rendered page.